# util-linux 2.25.2 lost credentials

Tags: linux, hyper-v

An employee, who left on bad terms, setup a linux server that we need access to but we can't login.

It is setup on a hyper-v VM.

When booted up it quickly loads the essential drivers then begins the bootup which is visible if you press the `ESC` key.

I will be honest and say I know nothing about linux, but once i get in I'm going to learn. I have tried googling and most everything seems to say to get into the Grub boot menu by either pressing `ESC` or holding `Left Shift` which is not working in my case.

Would really appreciate some help and will provide additional info if it is needed.